# Removing the event listener on a button programatically

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a button which is registered with a `onclick` event as shown

```
<Input type="Button" name="Register" Value="Register" onclick="CallMe();"/>
```

Is it possible to programatically remove or deregister the `onclick` event on this button?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could set the onclick attribute to `null`.

```
var el = document.getElementById('inputId');
el.onclick = null;
```

or better just remove the attribute altogether with the [`removeAttribute()` <sup>docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute) method of the element.

```
var el = document.getElementById('inputId');
el.removeAttribute('onclick');
```

you will need to add an id to the element though for this..

example code at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/PBjtZ/

Comment: or you can get the element by name

Comment: @meo, indeed. But there could be many with the same name, and i wanted to avoid explaining that he would need to make a loop.. But you are absolutely correct that there is that option..

Comment: removeAttribute('onclick') did not worked for me. `el.onclick = null;` did!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByName("Register")[0].onclick = ""
```

or

```
document.getElementsByName("Register")[0].removeAttribute("onclick")
```

Make sure to place this in a JS tag at the end of your document. So the DOM is available when this script is running.

the first example gets all elements with the name "Register" in your dom and returns the first, then it finds and sets the onclick attribute to an empty string. (could be null to)

the second example does the same, but removes the attribute "onclick".

Be careful if you have more then one element with the name "Register" you should do it like Gaby aka G. Petrioli told you to.